# spring data - query in array in object

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have an `EstablishmentEntity` which has an array of `Attachment`, i want to get the `EstablishmentEntity` that its `Attachments` contains an `Attachment` that its `idChild` equals the parameter i pass

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue
public class EstablishmentEntity extends ExerciseFrameworkEntity {

    @ElementCollection
    private Set<Attachment> attachments;

}

public class Attachment implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String idChild;

}
```

I tried with this, but i get this error

> Parameter value element [xxxxxxxx] did not match expected type
> Attachment

```
@Repository
public interface EstablishmentRepository extends JpaRepository<EstablishmentEntity, String> {
    
    EstablishmentEntity findByAttachmentsIn(String idChild);
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findByAttachmentsIn` expect List of `Attachment` for In query but you are passing String.

Use `IdChild` instead of `In` in method naming as you search by `idChild` of `Attachment`

```
EstablishmentEntity findByAttachmentsIdChild(String idChild);
```

Comment: i get this error: `Failed to create query for method public abstract EstablishmentEntity findByAttachmentsIdChild(java.lang.String)! Illegal attempt to dereference path source [null] of basic type`

Comment: Use @Embeddable in  Attachment class